# iOS 8 app download issue

Tags: ios, ios8

I have built the application in Xcode 6.1. It is not downloading in ios 8, showing the error `LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID: com......`. I have tried many solutions:

1. Postfixing some character in the `bundle-id` of the `plist`.
2. Downloaded the `provisioning profile` again.
3. List item

   Changed the `plist` by adding display-image and full-size-image tags.

When I implement these solutions, first 2-3 times it's getting downloaded, but after sometime it's failing.
I guess this can be an issue of `plist`.

I would like to know how to create a `plist` from `Xcode 6.1`?
Got a `plist` from .xarchive in `XCode 6.1`(shown below) but not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-   1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>ApplicationProperties</key>enter code here
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationPath</key>
    <string>https://....../App.ipa</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.abc.xyz.efg</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.40</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.40</string>
    <key>IconPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://....../icon-76.png</string>
        <string>https://....../icon-60.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>SigningIdentity</key>
    <string>Company Limited</string>
</dict>
<key>ArchiveVersion</key>
<integer>2</integer>
<key>CreationDate</key>
<date>2014-12-11T06:46:25Z</date>
<key>Name</key>
<string>App</string>
<key>SchemeName</key>
<string>App</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Cleaning and restarting the project helps?

Comment: No, I tried the below suggestion also. But failed. http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/30194-ios8-workaround-can-brea k-today-extension?full_site=1#comment_35141099   issue posted in apple forum also..https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6585456

Comment: Resolved this issue by changing  the ‘Build Active Architecture Only’ in Release to ‘No’. Used simple plist and use the workaround by postfixing ‘ios8fix’ in the plist file.